# Subset R dataframe by factor level, removing ALL rows after threshold crossed the FIRST time

Tags: r, time-series, subset, date-arithmetic

I have some web session data where I am trying to exclude ALL observations AFTER a certain amount of time (lets say 10 days) from the previous visit has passed.  I have an ID, a VisitNum, and a calculated DateDiff representing the days that have passed since the previous visit.  My ID's are factors so I need the solution to work across many factor levels.

Sample data:

```
test_data <- data.frame(ID=c("abc123","abc123","abc123","abc123"),
                    VisitNum=c(1,2,3,4),
                    DateDiff=c(0,5,30,5))
```

Since the 3rd visit occurred 30 days after the 2nd visit, I want to exclude BOTH the 3rd and 4th visit from the data frame.  The solutions I have come up with would exclude the 3rd visit but leave the 4th - which isn't what I need.

My desired result would look like this:

```
test_results <- data.frame(ID=c("abc123","abc123"),
                       VisitNum=c(1,2),
                       DateDiff=c(0,5))
```

Thanks!

Comment: Questions about how to code / manipulate data in R are off topic here. This will be on topic on [SO]. If you wait, we will try to migrate this for you.

Comment: Thanks @gung, sorry its been a while since I've used these forums.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this example, you can use the base R function `cummin`:

```
test_data[as.logical(cummin(test_data$DateDiff < 10)), ]
      ID VisitNum DateDiff
1 abc123        1        0
2 abc123        2        5
```

When applying this to multiple IDs, you can use the base R function `ave`:

```
test_data[as.logical(ave(test_data$DateDiff, test_data$ID,
                         FUN=function(i) cummin(i < 10))), ]
      ID VisitNum DateDiff
1 abc123        1        0
2 abc123        2        5
6 abc323        2        5
7 abc323        3        5
```

Here, `as.logical` is used because we are relying on logical subestting and `ave` returns the mode of the initial vector.

---

An equivalent operation in `data.table` would be

```
library(data.table
setDT(data.table)
test_data[as.logical(test_data[,cummin(DateDiff < 10), by=ID]$V1)]
```

**data**

```
test_data <- 
structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L),
.Label = c("abc123", "abc223", "abc323"), class = "factor"),
VisitNum = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 3), DateDiff = c(0, 5, 30, 5, 20, 5, 5)),
Names = c("ID", "VisitNum", "DateDiff"), row.names = c(NA, -7L),
class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Amazing work @lmo, works perfectly.  Thanks so much for your contribution!

Comment: Thanks. `cummin` is often overlooked, but can be pretty useful in these types of situations.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `which`.

```
test_data[1:(which(test_data$DateDiff > 10)[1] - 1),]
```

This is a little faster for larger datasets it seems

```
test_data <- data.frame(ID=sample(c("abc123","abc123","abc123","abc123"),2000,T),
                        VisitNum=1:2000,
                        DateDiff=sample(c(0,5,30,5),2000,T))

a <- function(dat) dat[1:(which(dat$DateDiff > 10)[1] - 1),]
b <- function(dat) dat[as.logical(cummin(dat$DateDiff < 10)), ]
microbenchmark(a(test_data), b(test_data), times = 1000)

## Unit: microseconds
##          expr     min       lq     mean  median      uq        max neval cld
##  a(test_data) 141.198 146.1895 197.6538 151.507 167.880   2326.238  1000  a 
##  b(test_data) 196.443 201.4810 496.1748 209.448 235.708 137785.448  1000   b
```

Function b took ~38% longer in median execution time over 1000 executions for a dataset with 2000 rows.